# I want to dual boot windows with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation

My computer originally had Windows 8 on it.  I completely reformatted my laptop and put Ubuntu 14.04 on it.  I tried using wine but It won't run my Technic launcher for Mine Craft.  I also can't get the Linux version of the Technic launcher to work.  So, I want to reinstall Windows 8 beside the Ubuntu so I can use the 8 for gaming and the Ubuntu for the rest of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Java to run Minecraft.

Install it from http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
then right-click launcher's .jar file, go to Properties > Open With, select Oracle Java 8 Runtime and set it as default. Double-click your launcher and it should run.

If you still want to install Windows 8, you'll need Ubuntu and Windows 8 discs. Boot from Ubuntu CD, run GParted, shrink your Linux partition and reboot to Windows 8 installation disc. Install Windows 8 on free space. Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do. Disable fast startup and shutdown your computer. Enter UEFI settings, find boot order, move ubuntu to the top and reboot. It should boot into Ubuntu, from there, run

```
sudo update-grub2
```

in Terminal and reboot. You should see GRUB menu with Ubuntu and Windows 8 now :)

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Minecraft is cross-platform, download the launcher in .jar version.
2. Shrink Ubuntu's partition and create NTFS in the unpartitioned space. Install Windows on NTFS partition and burn the boot-repair disk (you'll need it to reinstall grub). Disable Windows' fast and secure boot. Use the boot-repair cd and.. you're ready.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu, so I'm not really sure what any of this means.

Comment: Get new launcher, which is in .jar format (it'll be easier than reinstalling Windows).

Comment: I tried that but when I open up the launcher it's just a directory full of files.  How do I initiate it? Is there a terminal command or something I need to type in?

Comment: You have to install Java with typing "sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre"